# Creating an edge from a node in Java

Tags: java, graph, edges

I get an error whenever I try to create a simple edge from a node. 
Basically, I've created two of my own classes called Node and Edge.

The Node class is as follows:

```
public class Node {

    public String ident;
    public int numLinks;

    public Edge[] neighbours;


    public Node (String ident) {
        this.ident = ident;

    }

    public void setNeighbour (Node start, Node end, int cost, int portNum) {

    }
}
```

And my Edge class is as follows:

```
public class Edge {

   Node start;
   Node end;
   int cost;
   int portNum;

   public Edge (Node a, Node b, int cost, int portNum) {
       this.start = a;
       this.end = b;
       this.cost = cost;
       this.portNum = portNum;
   }
}
```

In my main class, I create two nodes, namely, the start and the end node. The cost and the port number (port number that both these nodes listen to on), I read from a text file and am saving them into an array list named "linkCostList" and "portNumList".

Now, since each start node can have more than one edge (I'm basically creating a graph), I'm calling the setNeighbour() method in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < startNode.numLinks; i++) {
    nextNode = new Node (String name of node I read from text file)
    startNode.setNeighbour (startNode, nextNode, linkCostList.get(i), portNumList.get(i));
}
```

My setNeighbour method is as follows:

```
public void setNeighbour (Node start, Node end, int cost, int portNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < start.numLinks; i++) {
        neighbours[i] = new Edge (start, end, cost, portNum);
    }
}
```

Whenever I compile it, I get an error of the following sort:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Node.setNeighbour(Node.java: *line number*)
    at Start.startlsr(Start.java: *line number*)
    at graph.main(lsr.java: *line number*)
}
```

I understand that this is a null pointer exception, so, somewhere in that loop, I must be doing something wrong. Could anyone please help me figure it out?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you initialzed `neighbours` in your `Node` class? It looks like the exception is from accessing a null array (`neighbours[i]`).

Also It looks like the `neighbours` array will grow/shrink dynamically? In this case, instead of using array, consider using ArrayList so you don't have to grow `neighbours` yourself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that actually does make sense. I would have something of the following, ArrayList<Edge> neighbours

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Alvin's answer (you haven't initialized neighbours nor allowed for expansion), try this:

```
public List<Edge> neighbours = new ArrayList<Edge>();
```

Also make use of java's "foreach":

```
    for (Edge edge : start.neighbours) {
        // .. some code
    }
```

Consider renaming "neighbours" to "edges", since they are just that - the edges of the node.

Finally, it seems you have a bug in your logic. It seems too complicated. You may be attempting to keep references of neighbours of neighbours. Consider simply looking stuff up when you need it.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a simple graph, its just in the form of a graph structure. I'm implementing link state routing. So I need to consider each neighbour and its port number so I can communicate with each node. Thanks for your input.